# What does requestValidationMode="2.0" actually do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation

I'm trying to solve a "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" problem, and SO answers and  [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) recommend setting

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

in Web.config (along with adding an attribute to problematic Methods).
I realize this changes the validation mode to ASP.NET 2.0's, but what does that mean?
And also, does this change has any side effects I should be aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the description at [MSDN's HttpRuntimeSection.RequestValidationMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode.aspx).

> **2.0**. Request validation is enabled only for pages, not for all HTTP requests. In addition, the request validation settings of the pages
>   element (if any) in the configuration file or of the @ Page directive
>   in an individual page are used to determine which page requests to
>   validate.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ASP.NET Request Validation](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147)>

> The request validation feature in ASP.NET provides a certain level of
>   default protection against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. In
>   previous versions of ASP.NET, request validation was enabled by
>   default. However, it applied only to ASP.NET pages (.aspx files and
>   their class files) and only when those pages were executing.
>
> In ASP.NET 4, by default, request validation is enabled for all
>   requests, because it is enabled before the BeginRequest phase of an
>   HTTP request. As a result, request validation applies to requests for
>   all ASP.NET resources, not just .aspx page requests. This includes
>   requests such as Web service calls and custom HTTP handlers. Request
>   validation is also active when custom HTTP modules are reading the
>   contents of an HTTP request.
>
> As a result, request validation errors might now occur for requests
>   that previously did not trigger errors. To revert to the behavior of
>   the ASP.NET 2.0 request validation feature, add the following setting
>   in the Web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

> However, we recommend that you analyze any request validation errors
>   to determine whether existing handlers, modules, or other custom code
>   accesses potentially unsafe HTTP inputs that could be XSS attack
>   vectors.